# Google recaptcha error in ie 11

Tags: internet-explorer, recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha

I am getting the following error in IE 11:

> SCRIPT5007: unable to get property "toString" of undefined or null
>   reference recaptcha__iw.js (451, 41)

Could it be possible that there is an error in the script?

Working on Safari, Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this line to your script where the file recaptcha_*.js is downloaded

```
document.querySelector('body').setActive();
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this? I'm using the following to generate the recaptcha file `<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onRecaptchaLoad&render=explicit" async defer></script>`, how should I add the extra line?

Comment: @chaonextdoor I used an angular service that wraps the Recaptcha and in the create function I pushed this line, you can use this line in Recaptcha on-create event

Comment: For me it worked to execute this line before recaptcha renders. (I'm calling grecaptcha.render explicitly after fetching the script programmatically. But executing the line before loading the script should als work imo.)

Comment: It works with IE, but Chrome return an error : `document.querySelector(...).setActive is not a function`. See my answer.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in IE10. `SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'setActive' of undefined or null reference`

Answer (score 6):

Add this meta on the html header to enable some HTML5 feature for Internet Explorer 11..

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

If it's not working then open **Compability View Settings** and remove google.com
Open developer tools and go to **Emulation** tab then change **document mode** to Edge..

If it's still not working then add this polyfill on the header..

```
<script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.js"></script>
```

Actually invisible recaptcha already supported for Android Stock Browser 4.0+ too.. So you don't need to worry if only old browser that doesn't supported..

Answer (score 6):

The answer of Ruthi works on *IE*, but not on *Google Chrome* (error at runtime), so, for a cross-browser solution, you need first to ensure that the browser can handle `querySelector().setActive`

So, put this *javascript* code before the recaptcha rendering:

```
if(document.querySelector('body').setActive != undefined)
{
    document.querySelector('body').setActive();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just add this polyfill (taked from cdn.polyfill.io)

```
(function(undefined) {

// Symbol
// A modification of https://github.com/WebReflection/get-own-property-symbols
// (C) Andrea Giammarchi - MIT Licensed

(function(Object, GOPS, global) {

  var setDescriptor;
  var id = 0;
  var random = '' + Math.random();
  var prefix = '__\x01symbol:';
  var prefixLength = prefix.length;
  var internalSymbol = '__\x01symbol@@' + random;
  var DP = 'defineProperty';
  var DPies = 'defineProperties';
  var GOPN = 'getOwnPropertyNames';
  var GOPD = 'getOwnPropertyDescriptor';
  var PIE = 'propertyIsEnumerable';
  var ObjectProto = Object.prototype;
  var hOP = ObjectProto.hasOwnProperty;
  var pIE = ObjectProto[PIE];
  var toString = ObjectProto.toString;
  var concat = Array.prototype.concat;
  var cachedWindowNames = typeof window === 'object' ? Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window) : [];
  var nGOPN = Object[GOPN];
  var gOPN = function getOwnPropertyNames(obj) {
    if (toString.call(obj) === '[object Window]') {
      try {
        return nGOPN(obj);
      } catch (e) {
        // IE bug where layout engine calls userland gOPN for cross-domain `window` objects
        return concat.call([], cachedWindowNames);
      }
    }
    return nGOPN(obj);
  };
  var gOPD = Object[GOPD];
  var create = Object.create;
  var keys = Object.keys;
  var freeze = Object.freeze || Object;
  var defineProperty = Object[DP];
  var $defineProperties = Object[DPies];
  var descriptor = gOPD(Object, GOPN);
  var addInternalIfNeeded = function(o, uid, enumerable) {
    if (!hOP.call(o, internalSymbol)) {
      try {
        defineProperty(o, internalSymbol, {
          enumerable: false,
          configurable: false,
          writable: false,
          value: {}
        });
      } catch (e) {
        o[internalSymbol] = {};
      }
    }
    o[internalSymbol]['@@' + uid] = enumerable;
  };
  var createWithSymbols = function(proto, descriptors) {
    var self = create(proto);
    gOPN(descriptors).forEach(function(key) {
      if (propertyIsEnumerable.call(descriptors, key)) {
        $defineProperty(self, key, descriptors[key]);
      }
    });
    return self;
  };
  var copyAsNonEnumerable = function(descriptor) {
    var newDescriptor = create(descriptor);
    newDescriptor.enumerable = false;
    return newDescriptor;
  };
  var get = function get() {};
  var onlyNonSymbols = function(name) {
    return name != internalSymbol &&
      !hOP.call(source, name);
  };
  var onlySymbols = function(name) {
    return name != internalSymbol &&
      hOP.call(source, name);
  };
  var propertyIsEnumerable = function propertyIsEnumerable(key) {
    var uid = '' + key;
    return onlySymbols(uid) ? (
      hOP.call(this, uid) &&
      this[internalSymbol]['@@' + uid]
    ) : pIE.call(this, key);
  };
  var setAndGetSymbol = function(uid) {
    var descriptor = {
      enumerable: false,
      configurable: true,
      get: get,
      set: function(value) {
        setDescriptor(this, uid, {
          enumerable: false,
          configurable: true,
          writable: true,
          value: value
        });
        addInternalIfNeeded(this, uid, true);
      }
    };
    try {
      defineProperty(ObjectProto, uid, descriptor);
    } catch (e) {
      ObjectProto[uid] = descriptor.value;
    }
    return freeze(source[uid] = defineProperty(
      Object(uid),
      'constructor',
      sourceConstructor
    ));
  };
  var Symbol = function Symbol(description) {
    if (this instanceof Symbol) {
      throw new TypeError('Symbol is not a constructor');
    }
    return setAndGetSymbol(
      prefix.concat(description || '', random, ++id)
    );
  };
  var source = create(null);
  var sourceConstructor = {
    value: Symbol
  };
  var sourceMap = function(uid) {
    return source[uid];
  };
  var $defineProperty = function defineProp(o, key, descriptor) {
    var uid = '' + key;
    if (onlySymbols(uid)) {
      setDescriptor(o, uid, descriptor.enumerable ?
        copyAsNonEnumerable(descriptor) : descriptor);
      addInternalIfNeeded(o, uid, !!descriptor.enumerable);
    } else {
      defineProperty(o, key, descriptor);
    }
    return o;
  };

  var onlyInternalSymbols = function(obj) {
    return function(name) {
      return hOP.call(obj, internalSymbol) && hOP.call(obj[internalSymbol], '@@' + name);
    };
  };
  var $getOwnPropertySymbols = function getOwnPropertySymbols(o) {
    return gOPN(o).filter(o === ObjectProto ? onlyInternalSymbols(o) : onlySymbols).map(sourceMap);
  };

  descriptor.value = $defineProperty;
  defineProperty(Object, DP, descriptor);

  descriptor.value = $getOwnPropertySymbols;
  defineProperty(Object, GOPS, descriptor);

  descriptor.value = function getOwnPropertyNames(o) {
    return gOPN(o).filter(onlyNonSymbols);
  };
  defineProperty(Object, GOPN, descriptor);

  descriptor.value = function defineProperties(o, descriptors) {
    var symbols = $getOwnPropertySymbols(descriptors);
    if (symbols.length) {
      keys(descriptors).concat(symbols).forEach(function(uid) {
        if (propertyIsEnumerable.call(descriptors, uid)) {
          $defineProperty(o, uid, descriptors[uid]);
        }
      });
    } else {
      $defineProperties(o, descriptors);
    }
    return o;
  };
  defineProperty(Object, DPies, descriptor);

  descriptor.value = propertyIsEnumerable;
  defineProperty(ObjectProto, PIE, descriptor);

  descriptor.value = Symbol;
  defineProperty(global, 'Symbol', descriptor);

  // defining `Symbol.for(key)`
  descriptor.value = function(key) {
    var uid = prefix.concat(prefix, key, random);
    return uid in ObjectProto ? source[uid] : setAndGetSymbol(uid);
  };
  defineProperty(Symbol, 'for', descriptor);

  // defining `Symbol.keyFor(symbol)`
  descriptor.value = function(symbol) {
    if (onlyNonSymbols(symbol))
      throw new TypeError(symbol + ' is not a symbol');
    return hOP.call(source, symbol) ?
      symbol.slice(prefixLength * 2, -random.length) :
      void 0;
  };
  defineProperty(Symbol, 'keyFor', descriptor);

  descriptor.value = function getOwnPropertyDescriptor(o, key) {
    var descriptor = gOPD(o, key);
    if (descriptor && onlySymbols(key)) {
      descriptor.enumerable = propertyIsEnumerable.call(o, key);
    }
    return descriptor;
  };
  defineProperty(Object, GOPD, descriptor);

  descriptor.value = function(proto, descriptors) {
    return arguments.length === 1 || typeof descriptors === "undefined" ?
      create(proto) :
      createWithSymbols(proto, descriptors);
  };
  defineProperty(Object, 'create', descriptor);

  descriptor.value = function() {
    var str = toString.call(this);
    return (str === '[object String]' && onlySymbols(this)) ? '[object Symbol]' : str;
  };
  defineProperty(ObjectProto, 'toString', descriptor);


  setDescriptor = function(o, key, descriptor) {
    var protoDescriptor = gOPD(ObjectProto, key);
    delete ObjectProto[key];
    defineProperty(o, key, descriptor);
    if (o !== ObjectProto) {
      defineProperty(ObjectProto, key, protoDescriptor);
    }
  };

}(Object, 'getOwnPropertySymbols', this));}).call('object' === typeof window && window || 'object' === typeof self && self || 'object' === typeof global && global || {});
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to remove

```js
import '@babel/polyfill
```

inside my bundled js file (through this Symbol.Iterator was overwritten and caused the trouble).