# How i can set active for HtmlBodyElement?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

i try use this method:

```
document.querySelector('body').setActive();
```

but have error:

```
TS2339: Property 'setActive' does not exist on type 'HTMLBodyElement'.
```

How i can fix then? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The [`setActive()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Gecko/Chrome/API/Browser_API/setActive) only appears on `<iframe>` elements which shouldn't be used anyway:

> This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

Comment: Hm, it looks like this was the only normal solution for
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47669463/google-recaptcha-error-in-ie-11
maybe you have any alternatives about this? Thanks!